# Outputting Spectrogram with Scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spectrogram

I am reading a wavfile and trying to graph the audio data. The scipy wave.read function organizes the sound data in an array of two columns (4351200, 2). Unfortunately, signal.spectrogram errors out, with an unexpected dimension error.

I tried to flatten the sound data using np.reshape, np.hsplit, np.flatten. I no longer get the dimension error (seems that is one of the core of the issue), but the output graph is blank. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np

sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read('C:\\Users\\tkim1\\Desktop\\WAV 
sounds\\ANNOY 1m38s angry_cow.wav')

frequencies, times, spectrogram = signal.spectrogram(samples, sample_rate)

plt.pcolormesh(times, frequencies, spectrogram) #the time series does not make sense when i just flatten the data. it is now twice as long.
plt.imshow(spectrogram)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()
```

Comment: could you print out the shapes for all the variables? Maybe that would help to understand...

Comment: If this is a time series, you don't want to use `pcolormesh` which is for plotting 2D data